# Add data into arraylist of other servlet

Tags: servlets

The web app exists out off 2 servlets, one will return the planning of the kitchen as a series of timestamps that are still available for customers to place their orders. And the second servlet has the function to place new orders into the system.

The orders can come from 2 locations, either the database of the cashregister (for physical visitors to our business or via phone) or via the online ordering system (based upon woo commerce)

I already made one servlet that does the planning based upon the database. The planning is done every time the doGet method is called via a php curl in the plugin i've made for woo-commerce.

Now I want to make a second part in my plugin that will inject the order into the same planning via a second servlet. But I am wondering add this new order received in the ordering servlet to the arraylist that is contains the orders of the planning servlet?

Comment: Use Map to inject it into Planning with panning as key and which has equals and hadhCode in it if you want HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharp edge's solution is based on a deprecated API and cannot be use with decent versions of Java EE. But using the ServletContext to keep variables common to different servlet is still a correct way.

You could :

- use the `contextInitialized` method of a `ServletContextListener` to initialize the ArrayList and store it as a ServletContext attribue
- use `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("attribute_name")` in both servlets to get access to the ArrayList.

Alternatively, you could create a service class in charge of the array list management and put it as an attribute is the ServletContext or inject it in your Servlets if you use Spring Framework or a full Java EE container (not Tomcat ...)

Comment: Should I also add serialization in the contextDestroyed method so that once the tomcat server shutsdown (e.g. if the power goes out, or the physical server crashes) ? So that no data gets lost

Comment: @DenUil : Yes it a a good place to ensure everything was saved. But I strongly advice you not to wait contextDestroyed to serialize data. If you have a nice shutdown of the webapp, all will be fine ; but in case of crash, the contextDestroyed could not be called, or be called when disk or database cannot be written to ...

Answer (score 0):

A servlet obtains information about other servlets through the *ServletContext* object. Use *getServlet()* to get a particular servlet:

```
public Servlet ServletContext.getServlet(String name) throws ServletException
```

This method returns the servlet of the given name, or *null* if the servlet is not found. The specified name can be the servlet's registered name (such as "file") or its class name (such as *"com.sun.server.webserver.FileServlet")*. The server maintains one servlet instance per name, so getServlet("file") returns a different servlet instance than *getServlet("com.sun.server.webserver.FileServlet")*.

[Source found here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch11_01.htm)

When you have the instance of the servlet you can get what you want if communicating between two servlets is required. OR you can use the good old static *arraylist* in a different class and store the result in that, and then whenever you need that list simply call it using the classes name.

Comment: This is a deprecated API **do not use it** : it will return null ! Extract from javadoc : *Servlet getServlet(java.lang.String name) Deprecated. As of Java Servlet API 2.1, with no direct replacement. This method was originally defined to retrieve a servlet from a ServletContext. In this version, this method always returns null and remains only to preserve binary compatibility*

Comment: You are most welcome to suggest an alternative to OP.